# mysql query about sum of rows with each row having unique id

Tags: mysql, join, subquery

I am really new to mysql.  I am getting candy_id and order# as the input(shown by *). I want an output that will add chocolate and mocha quantities. I have tried many queries using aggregates, group by but I am unable to get the result. I have not tried JOIN.  Please help.

Process: the whole process is...I will query another table to get bunch of candy_id. order # is a fixed number(6). Then I use both of these in this table to get the candy-type and their respective cumulative  quantities. Sorry for the confusion. I have a tough time presenting the problem

```
So the output will be

 candy_type    Total qty
  Chocolate     14
  Mocha         25



The database table is
    candy_id    candy_type    order#      qty
        1*        Chocolate     6*         12
        2         Vanilla       1          10
        3*        Mocha         6*         20
        4*        Chocolate     6*        2
        5         Orange        1          10
        6*        Mocha         6*         5
        7         Chocolate     6         13
        8         Chocolate     6          7
```

How can i reduce abpve table to below using query and do an aggregate query? Is there a way to do such back to back queries

```
   candy_id    candy_type    order#      qty
        1*        Chocolate     6*         12
        3*        Mocha         6*         20
        4*        Chocolate     6*         2
        6*        Mocha         6*         5
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be pretty simple, I think

```
SELECT candy_type, SUM(qty) AS total_qty
FROM table
GROUP BY candy_type
WHERE order_id IN (6, 12)
AND candy_id IN (
  SELECT id
  FROM candy
  WHERE vendor = "foo"
  AND location = "bar"
)
ORDER BY candy_name ASC;
```

---

You could also do this using a `JOIN`

```
SELECT
  table.candy_type,
  SUM(table.qty) AS total_qty

FROM table

JOIN candy
  ON candy.id       = table.candy_id
 AND candy.vendor   = "foo"
 AND candy.location = "bar"


GROUP BY table.candy_type
WHERE table.order_id IN (6, 12)
ORDER BY table.candy_name ASC;
```

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. My table was not representing the true problem. I have updated the table(modified rows  and 8) now to show the real issue. Can you please comment now?

Comment: I suppose you could use something like `IN (1, 3, 4, 6)` to narrow it to specific rows

Comment: the whole process is...I will query another table to get bunch of candy_id. order # is a fixed number(6). Then I use both of these in this table to get the candy-type and their respective quantities. Sorry for the confusion. I have a tough time presenting the problem

Comment: Anybody? Really need help on this one

Comment: @vikas, what are the inputs to aggregate the data? Are we summing based on the `order_id`?

Comment: summing based on candy_id and order#. Order# can only be 6, 12. but candy_id could be any number based on query result from another table.

Comment: vikas, how are you getting the `candy_id` result from the other table? What are the conditions there?

Comment: I am using vendor and its location name as conditions

Comment: vikas, I've modified my post to show the subquery that might work. I'm not sure how your second table is structured, though.

Comment: In the future, I recommend that you show us all tables and relevant columns involved in your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
select candy_type, sum(qty) from
your table
where order# = order_number in your parameter
and candy_id in (your candy_id parameter)
group by candy_type
```

Comment: this one does not add up the quantities. Shows 4 rows, 2 with chocolate 12 and 2 and 2 rows with Mocha 20 and 5